# Как получить ЛС от группы?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Господа, помогите решить проблему.
Для начала немного информации. В группах ВКонтакте есть возможность активировать прием сообщений, а также написать текст. Этот текст будет отправляться пользователям, которые впервые открывают диалог с группой. Я получаю сообщения, когда захожу через браузер в этот диалог.

Теперь о коде. В своем приложении через API отправляю сообщение в группу (метод messages.send). Сообщение отправляется и получается, с этим проблем нет. Проблема в том, что в ответ не приходит введенное ранее сообщение-ответ от группы. Как исправить ситуацию?

Наверняка такая возможность есть. Пользуюсь мобильным приложением-клиентом для этой социальной сети (Kate mobile). Если перехожу в диалог, - вижу свое отправленное (через API) сообщение и тут же получаю ответ от группы. Также и с web-версией.

Comment: Попробуйте после или перед отправкой сообщения вызвать метод [messages.getHistory](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory) (если не ошибся в названии метода), чтобы ВК подумал, что вы открыли диалог с сообществом.

Comment: @terron Благодарю вас! Помогло! Напишите в ответ, отмечу вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно дать ВК понять, что вы открыли диалог с сообществом. Сделать это можно, обратившись к методу, который выводит сообщения из диалога: [messages.getHistory](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory).